# What is the best way to overwrite a file?

Tags: python, filesystems

Consider the following program that overwrites a huge data file.

```
with open('datafile', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(100000):
        line = 'x' * 1000 + '\n'
        f.write(line)
```

If you type Control-C while writing, the previous contests of `datafile` will get lost, and only a part of the new contents will be written. I found two solutions to avoid the data loss. The first is to use `os.replace`.

```
import os

with open('tmpfile', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(100000):
        line = 'x' * 1000 + '\n'
        f.write(line)

os.replace('tmpfile', 'datafile')
```

In this way, `datafile` never gets lost because python [assures the atomicity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) of `os.replace`. However, if there is a hard link of `datafile`, it will retain the old contents.

The second is trap signals that cause program termination.

```
import signal

# makes exit signals ignored and returns the previous handlers
def ignore_exit_signals():
    signals = [signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGQUIT, signal.SIGTERM]
    handler_dictionary = {}
    for sig in signals:
        handler_dictionary[sig] = signal.getsignal(sig)
        signal.signal(sig, signal.SIG_IGN)
    return handler_dictionary

def restore_exit_signal_handlers(handler_dictionary):
    for sig, handler in handler_dictionary.items():
        signal.signal(sig, handler)

handler_dictionary = ignore_exit_signals()
with open('datafile', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(100000):
        line = 'x' * 1000 + '\n'
        f.write(line)
restore_exit_signal_handlers(handler_dictionary)
```

This doesn't cause the hard link problem, but the termination signals will be ignored for a long time.

I think that I must use the second way, but I'm not sure. Which is the better? Or do you have another good idea?

Comment: so you are writing to a temp file and replacing the old with the temp only if the write is successful, won't datafile be overwritten though anyway? Or are you appending `"a"` to your actual files?

Comment: I'd just not care about hard links, really. Note that even trapping programming signals is not infallible. The user can still hard-kill the process, for example.